# add new column (string length) to df by UserDefinedFunction in spark python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have dataframe with 2 columns name, age.
I would like to add new column, name_length, which contain the str.count(name) value.

code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import UserDefinedFunction
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

udf = UserDefinedFunction(lambda x: str.count(x.alias(name)), DoubleType())
df_with_new_column = nonull_df.withColumn('name_length', udf())
print df_with_new_column.show()
```

when i run this, I receive the error:
 `"ValueError: (ValueError('No args or kwargs',), <function <lambda> at 0x7feac13329b0>, ())"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As David Griffin said earlier, you don't need a UDF for this as there is a built in function length() in pyspark sql functions. Just to clarify his answer with out-of-the-box working code, you'll need to call the method from pyspark sql functions as below.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = df.withColumn('your_column_length', F.length(your_column))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Every answer on SO should fully answer the question on its own. Please use to edit feature to improve other answers if you think you can make them better

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `UDF` for this. There is a built in function called `length()`. You should be able to do:

```
SELECT length(your_column_name_here) as name_length
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `str.count` doesn't compute the length. It is used to get

   > the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in
   >   string S[start:end].

   and it requires at least two arguments string and pattern
2. Argument you receive inside `udf` is plain Python object not a column. It won't have `alias` method.
3. You define UDF which takes a single argument but pass none (direct source of the error).
4. Finally there is already built-in [`size` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.size) which handles this.